# Given that $f(z)$ and $|f(z)|$ are each analytic in a domain D, prove that $f(z)$ is constant in D.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I began to answer this proof and got stuck in middle of it.

Given: $f(z)$ is analytic in the domain D, $|f(z)|$ is analytic in the domain D.

Proof: $f(z)$ is constant in D.

$f(z) = u + iv$ , where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued function in the domain D. By hypothesis, $f(z)$ is analytic and Cauchy-Riemann Equations holds.

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$

then

$|f(z)|$ , where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued function in the domain D and the Cauchy-Riemann Equations holds.

$|f(z)| = \sqrt{u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)} \rightarrow |f(z)|^2 = u^2(x,y) + v^2(x,y)$. Then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} (u^2) = 2uu_x$ , $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} (v^2) = 2vv_y$ , $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} (u^2) = 2uu_y$ , $-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} (u^2) = -2uu_x$.

This is where I am confused where to go to show its constant or not.

Comment: write $g(z)= \vert f(z)\vert$, show $g$ is constant, then show $f$ is constant.  It's worth pointing out that there is no continuous invertible map from a (2-d) standard disc to the real line (this is Borsuk-Ulam but it's implied by 1-d real analysis), yet since $g$ is analytic, if it had non-zero derivative somewhere, then by inverse function theorem it would have an invertible mapping from some small disc to the real line.  So $g$ is has zero derivative everywhere and by mean value inequality it is constant.  A similar argument shows $f$ is constant though there are more direct approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the only real-valued analytic functions are constant.

Comment: how do I prove that?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations are one way.